# How to send a TCP request with payload in Java

Tags: java, android, tcp, tcpclient

We are working for the Camera integration project, we have connected this camera through wifi ( camera act as a server), for interrations camera company provides TCP protocol, I have confused to how to send a request for this. We are trying this in JAVA. Please help us to understand this communication protocols.

[image: This is communication structre]

[image: TCP Header]

[image: Message Constructon]

Please give a hint or idea to commuction with this device.

We have tried below code and its not worked as expected.

```
try {
    // Create a socket to connect to the server
    Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.150.1", 31000);

    // Send the payload
    OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
    out.write(25004);
    out.flush();

    // Receive the payload
    InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead = in.read(buffer);
    String response = new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    System.out.println("Response from server: " + response);

    // Close the socket
    socket.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: `out.write(25004);` Please explain this code.

Comment: We really don't how to pass the values so we used this way

[link] (https://imgur.com/a/wWQ5P1e)

Comment: No links please. Only code. It is unclear what you wanna pass. You did not tell that. First tell what you wanna send. Then show the code doing so. Dont expect us to understand that 25004 which would be a four byte integer i think.